# What is the difference between the NSImage and UIImage?

Tags: objective-c

what is the basic differences in using NSImage and UIImage for iPhone?

Comment: Is there any abstraction library that can serve both platforms?

Comment: You can't use `NSImage` in iPhone programming. It's part of a framework that is available on OS X, not iOS.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

UIKit (iPhone) defines`UIImage` and AppKit (Mac OS X) defines `NSImage`, you use the one for the platform you are targeting. (Be more specific if you want more specific answers.)